# Is there any method to connect SAGE 50 data to Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, odbc, powerbi-desktop, sage-erp, sage50

So i have my whole business data in SAGE 50 UK, i want to import the data (sales...) from SAGE 50 to Power BI desktop to create a dashboard but unfortunately Power BI doesn't support importing data directly from SAGE, is there any solid method to do that to import live data from SAGE 50 to Power BI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For data sources not directly supported by Power BI Connectors, you need to investigate the APIs or Data Export options available.  Power BI can connect directly over Rest, OData, or using an ODBC or OleDB driver.  And can load exported data in any common format.

So start here [Sage 50 Import/Export Overview](https://help-sage50.na.sage.com/en-us/2019/Content/Importing_Exporting/Import_Export_Overview.htm) to see what options are available.